# Is "many of them doing" in this sentence correct?

Tags: grammar, conjunctions, clauses

> The musical scene was a maze of competing movements and slogans, many
>   of them claiming to be “new” in one way or another.

I am reading the book [Music in the Twentieth and Twenty-First Centuries](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0393929205) and on page 106 I thought the sentence above seems ungrammatical according to [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/177673/10484). To my knowledge that is a run-on sentence and should be connected by a certain conjunction like "and" or "then" or "but" or "either" or others.

> The musical scene was a maze of competing movements and slogans, and many
>   of them claimed to be “new” in one way or another.

Another correction is like this:

> The musical scene was a maze of competing movements and slogans, many
>   of which claimed to be “new” in one way or another.

But I don't know why it should be "claiming" rather than "claimed"?

I have read [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/14670/10484), but it seems too sketchy for me to understand..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is fine as it is. It's not a run-on sentence.

The answer you reference is discussing how it's ungrammatical to join two independent clauses with a comma and without a conjunction. But the sentence in your question is a main (independent) clause that's followed by a nonessential relative (dependent) clause.

Consider your sentence:

> **The musical scene was a maze of competing movements and slogans,** *many of them claiming to be "new" in one way or another*.

You could drop everything in italics and still have a grammatical sentence. Syntactically speaking, what follows the comma is simply acting to give additional (but ultimately unneeded) information about the main clause.

Other examples of this would be:

> **I walked carefully up the stairs,** *being careful to mind my sore foot*.
>   **I walked down the hallway,** *cautiously avoiding its freshly painted walls*.
>   **I joined my friend at the bar,** *who had started drinking without me*.

---

Past participle verbs will work with other verbs of any tense, so **claiming** will always work (although you may need a helper verb along with it—such as *were claiming*, *are claming* or *will be claiming*—in some constructions).

It doesn't *have* to be **claiming**, but it can be. If you use something other than just **claiming**, you need to make sure it uses a verb tense that matches what's used at the start of the sentence.

Take your first alternative sentence. It doesn't use **claiming** but it's a fine alternative because it uses the past tense:

> The musical scene **was** a maze of competing movements and slogans, and many of them **claimed** to be "new" in one way or another.

We could also take your second alternative sentence (which, unlike the first, is another example of the use of a relative clause) and change both verbs to the present tense:

> The musical scene **is** a maze of competing movements and slogans, many of which **claim** to be "new" in one way or another.

Comment: I have updated my question, then please update your awesome answer.

Comment: @zhang I have updated my answer to match your revised question.